# Show a bootstrap modal next to another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to make a bootstrap modal appear in a position relative to another modal? I've tried using the "left" css attribute like this:

```
var leftPosition = $('#myModal .modal-content').offset().left + $('#myModal .modal-content').width();
$('#aditionalModal').css('left', leftPosition);
$('#aditionalModal').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500).modal('toggle');
```

It kinda does the job, but the position of the second modal remains fixed on re-size, a behavior I would like to avoid. Basically, I would like the second modal to appear next to the first one, and keep a constant distance between them on re-size. [Button on the first modal, which would trigger the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xhA.png)

[Simplified version of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/xzaz5fr6/)

Comment: I have done similar (not exactly the same) in my project. If you could share your code in a fiddler, it will be easy to provide a solution.

Comment: Here is the simplified code 
https://jsfiddle.net/xzaz5fr6/

Comment: And how do you want them to display on mobile devices? They will not fit horizontally.

Comment: I thought about using bootstrap classes to show the second one below the first one or vice versa.